# iOS project run in iOS11 will stuck in a program launchscreen

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11

I have a iOS project here, which runs on xcode8.

Applestore version, installed in the iOS11 device, the program will always stuck in the launchscreen.

When I run this project with xcode9, the same is true of the ios11 emulator.
The project is running on the ios11 device or emulator, and will be stuck at the launchscreen, but there is no error.

I tried to set binary 64 bits, just the same question.

Has anyone ever met this problem?

Comment: I also have some doubts about the binary system of the third party components in the project